# Deploying C# Windows Service in multiple servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows, windows-service

I've created a C# windows service and its ready to be deployed. I have 215 servers on which this windows service is to be installed.

I have to login to each box and deploy the service. Is there an automated way to enter the a list of server names and deploy the service in all the listed servers at one shot?

Thank you,
Vinay

Comment: just as a side note: I guess you "earnded" the downvote because of the bad "tagging" - maybe someone with sufficient rights can retag this?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what operating systems are involved.

Comment: Hi CKoenig, thanks for your comments. By the way, I'm new to this forum and working to identify each area. I may have missed the tagging properly. :( .Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Hi Anthony, only Windows 2003 and 2008 servers are involved. thank you.

Comment: There you go, Vinay. Tags edited for you. Welcome to Serverfault!

Comment: Is there no click once type of setup for windows services? Where they check a central location for a new version, and if its there it then installs it.

Answer (score 3):

If the servers are part of an Active Directory domain then you can create a .msi installer for your service and deploy it through Active Directory.

See [**this question**](https://serverfault.com/questions/13111/how-is-software-deployed-via-active-directory) for the steps to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can be done using WMI and PowerShell remoting. Here's some links of that nature:

- http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2011/03/07/how-to-install-powershell-on-windows-server-2003-and-enable-remote-powershell-management-all-servers-should-have-this-done.aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662309/install-windows-service-on-a-remote-machine-using-powershell-2-0