# How to go about deploying windows services to a number of nodes

Tags: windows, deployment, windows-service

I have about a dozen windows service which I need to deploy fairly frequently to a fairly large collection of nodes. I was looking at [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/) which seemed pretty good but I was wondering what other options there might be. I really need to be able to keep track of what versions of the software are deployed where and when so I'm looking for something a bit more than just powershelling in and deploying. I've looked at [Deploying C# Windows Service in multiple servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/301996/deploying-c-windows-service-in-multiple-servers) but I would eat an entire pint of Ben and Jerry's before I use an MSI.

I also have a bunch of web sites which it would be really good if I could roll them out with the same solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why the hate against an MSI?  If you used an MSI you could deploy against the servers using AD.

Comment: I once had a job where I had to use InstallShield. It was terrible. Also I really like Ben and Jerry's so it isn't that much hate.

Comment: LOL, hey don't get me wrong. Ben and Jerry's is pretty awesome.  I'm all over hating on MSI if I get Ben and Jerry's for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have anything against running an ssh server on each of your target servers you could use [kwateeSDCM](http://sdcm.kwatee.net) to deploy your services.